# Device Preview Configuration in SDL Tridion

Tags: configuration, preview

We are in the process of outlining data and files needed to set up our Device Preview configuration file.  Does anyone have tips from a successful implementation?  Did anyone have a good source for the preview image files?  Or any other feedback on where to pull the user agent info and other details required in the configuration file?

Comment: Is this 2011 or 2013? In 2013 it's built in, there's no additional work other than installing and using Experience Manager.

Comment: 2013.  I'm asking about the values it sounds like we need to add to the Devices.xml file as part of Device Preview confguration.  

Does the Devices.xml file come populated with standard device configuations and does SDL provide the image/graphid files needed as well?  I thought we had to define all this information ourselves and wanted to get tips/trcks from others.

Comment: Nope, it comes pre-defined with images and devices. Top of my head, about 15 devices are already there. You can add or modify devices, but these should provide a good start.

Comment: @user1042 have you had any luck finding the DeviceImages for up-to-date iphones - For example: appleiphone6_portrait.png or appleiphone6_landscape.png? Do you have to grab them from the xcode emulator sdk for iphones? I was able to find the user agent string here: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-iPhone-6-and-iPhone-6-plus-user-agent

Comment: Hi - I did not ever locate out-of-the box additional images, outside of what is provided as standard with the SDL install.  We wound up not moving forward with this feature for now, so I did not need to pursue any further.  Wish I had more info for you :)